# select only first and then ignore rows where values in two colums are the same

Tags: mysql, sql

Example table:

```
 id    foo   bar
 1      2    877
 2      2    877
 3      3    678
 4      4    887
 5      1    678
 6      2    887
```

Example results:

```
 id    foo   bar
 3      3    678
 4      4    887
 5      1    678
 6      2    887
```

The sql ignores the duplicates of 2 and 887 but not the latest one.

Foo will be specified beforehand.

How can this be achieved in MYSQL?

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right you always want the `bar` value to a `foo` with the highest `id`.

```
select * 
  from your_table t1
 where id = (select max(id)  from your_table t2
                            where t2.foo = t1.foo)
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f476c/14) for a demo. It also gives an alternative way with a left join. The construct does assume that the "latest one" is the one with the highest id.

**EDIT:** So according to your comment you only want that "highest id" for foo=2, that is a simply `OR` logic. I don't know if foo can be null so I added the `IS NULL` condition otherwise the `<>` might not work.

```
select * from your_table t1
where  foo <> 2 or foo is null
   or  (foo = 2 and id = (select max(id)  from your_table t2
                                         where t2.foo = t1.foo) ) ;
```

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24dd2/4)

Comment: I only want the highest id when foo is 2 for all foo 2 values, the rest i wanted selected as usual

Comment: Well, you have to learn a little bit of SQL yourself and don't just ask for code. This is SO where normally people show some of there code and then get hints how to solve it. So I almost regret that I answered you in the first place. But since I started it I will try to make this a success, will edit the answer.